# Prove $\int_{\mathbb R^d}|x-y|^{\alpha -d}|y|^{\beta -d}dy=C|x|^{\alpha +\beta -d}$

Tags: real-analysis

Could someone give me a link where the following formula has been proved

$$\int_{\mathbb R^d}|x-y|^{\alpha -d}|y|^{\beta -d}dy=\frac{c_{d-\alpha-\beta  }c_{\alpha  }c_\beta }{c_{\alpha +\beta }c_{d-\alpha }c_{d-\beta }}|x|^{\alpha +\beta -d},$$
where $$c_\alpha =\frac{\Gamma(\alpha /2)}{\pi^{-\alpha /2}}.$$

I don't need to prove it, I just need to use it. Better I would like to give a reference where it can be proved.

Comment: If you don't care about the proof, why do you need a reference? Do you doubt it is true?

Comment: @Jeff: No, I use it in my thesis and thus, I need a reference to justify it's true.

Comment: I'm not sure of a reference, but it is just a convolution $(f*g)(x) =\int f(x-y)g(y)\, dy$. I would try using the Fourier transform to prove the identity.

Answer (score 0):

Note there are some restrictions on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to make the left hand side integrable: $\alpha,\beta>0$ and $\alpha+\beta<d$. Given these restrictions, it is easy to prove the result with a scaling argument: Let $f(x)$ denote the left hand side, and note that $f(\lambda x) = \lambda^{\alpha+\beta-d}f(x)$ for any $\lambda > 0$ by making a change of variables in the integral. Therefore

$$f(x) = f\left(\frac{x}{|x|}\right)|x|^{\alpha + \beta - d}.$$

Then argue by symmetry that $f$ is constant on $\partial B_1=\{|x|=1\}$ and so

$$f(x) = f(e_1)|x|^{\alpha + \beta - d}.$$

Then you just need to compute $f(e_1)$. If you don't care what the constant is then you are done.